# A nice use of $AM GM HM$ inequality

Tags: optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a+b+c = 20$. Then what is the minimum value of $1/a + 9/b + 36/c$ .In this question minimum value is asked. How to approach it as we can find maximum value by applying $GM $ and $HM$ inequality.

Comment: are $a,b,c$ assumed to be positive?

Comment: Why tag arithmetic-geometry?

Comment: Yes they are positive

Comment: Sorry friend for wrong tagging

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post. Also, this page may be of use to you: codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php.

Comment: Just remember to write code inside the dollar signs, for example do not write \frac{1}{2} but write $\frac{1}{2}$ - otherwise your code will not be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

We have,
$$ a + b + c = 20 $$
rewriting as -
$$ a + (b/3 + ... 3 times) + (c/6 + ... 6 times) = 20 \tag 1$$
now, we have to find -
$$ 1/a + (3/b + .. 3 times) + (6/c + ... 6 times) \tag 2$$
Since a,b,c are all positive numbers, we can apply AM > HM. Treat (2)/10 as AM and 10/(1) as HM -
$$ \frac{(2)}{10} \ge \frac {10}{(1)} $$
Solve for minimum value of (2). Equality holds.

Comment: Thanks for the help and suggestions

Comment: you're welcome. Just to remind you, you can mark this answer as correct if you believe that it answers your question.